# Can you have more than two responses to np.where

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following np.where statement

```
df['DCC'] = np.where((df['RxDate'] - df['ABdat']).dt.days > 0, 0, df['DCC']
```

If the difference between ABdat and RxDate > 0 then it assigns 0 to DCC if not DCC remains as it was.

If the difference  between ABdat and RxDate > 0 I would like to assign 0 to DCC and assign another column AbCode == 1 on the same row.

I could write a second np.where statement however I was wondering if it was possible to incorporate multiple responses into np.where

For example

```
df['DCC'] = np.where((df['RxDate'] - df['ABdat']).dt.days > 0, (0 & df['AbCode']==1), df['DCC']
```

This did not give an error however it did not toggle AbCode to 1

Comment: `0 & (another bit sequence)` is always going to be false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
mask = (df['RxDate'] - df['ABdat']).dt.days > 0
df.loc[mask, ['DCC', 'AbcCode']] = [0,1]
```

Comment: Your code delivered for the outcome I was looking for.  Thanks